# Query data from MongoDB to Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am quite new to coding and I need to query data I have stored as json objects in MongoDB. I have read about nodejs but I am quite unsure how to start with this. Does anyone have good reading tips or a description of how to start?

```js
//====================================================
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/PlotLayoutOptions';
const dbName = 'Vitboken';
var recievedObj = [];

//====================================================
// Use connect method to connect to the server
//====================================================
MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, client)
{
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");

  const db = client.db(dbName);

  //Query All Evaluation results
  var query = {__Tag__: 'Evaluation'};
   db.collection('Alt_0').find(query).toArray(function(err, result)
   {
    if (err) throw err;
    recievedObj = result;
    console.log(recievedObj);
  });

  //Close the client connection
  client.close();
});

  //====================================================
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
      <title>DesignDashboard</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script><!-- Load d3.js -->
      <script src="connectToMongo.js"></script>
      <link href="Style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli" rel="stylesheet"> <!--Google fonts -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui-ieshiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script scr="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Check the docs over here: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/quick-start/quick-start/, they include how to start with a fresh node project, including how to install modules and run the code.

Comment: Here's a full course on Node: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RLtyhwFtXQA

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question is a bit too broad to be on-topic here. You could start by installing nodejs, mongodb, then set up a nodejs project with `npm init`, install the mongodb driver with `npm install mongodb`, then follow the [docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/). If you get stuck at a specific point, create an [mcve] and ask that, we will be glad to help you then :)

Comment: The NetNinja is a YouTube channel with some really great videos for beginners for both learning NodeJS and using NodeJS with MongoDB. Heres the link to his playlist for Node and Mongo for beginners. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9jpvoYriLI0bY8DOgWZfi6u

Comment: I have managed to query the data from my mongo database in the nodejs command prompt. And I have set up a HTML page with javascript where I display test data. The problem now is how to connect the query data with my javascript. I get the error message that I am missing a reference. I will upload my code at the top of this page

Comment: So my question is: why does it work from nodejs command promt but not from my HTML code? I have inserted the reference to the connectToMongo.js script in the head but even though I dont call any methods from js I and up with the error "require is not defined"....

Answer (score 2):

You can just start with any tutorials like one I mentioned below.
considering you know the basic of Javascript.

- Step 1 -> create server in node
- Step 2 -> connect with database
- Step 3 -> apply CRUD operations

[Getting started with Node and Mongo](https://codeburst.io/writing-a-crud-app-with-node-js-and-mongodb-e0827cbbdafb)